# Text color is the same as the background in Conemu

Tags: conemu

I'm running `npm start` and the result is shown below. The font color for some reason is the same as the background. I tried fiddling around with a lot of controls, including the theme, font colors, etc but no luck.

Any idea as to why Conemu can't handle this? Looks fine in the normal Windows cmd. Other commands work fine, and this is the only command I've had issues with in Conemu so far.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happened to me whilst using Node. I fixed it is by adding a background image.

Settings > Background > Path.

Comment: Can you explain with Conemu how to change background color?

Comment: Thank you. This solved the issue perfectly. You can darken the image in `settings` to completely make it disappear without resurfacing the problem.